# How in windows create process as user using python?

Tags: python, winapi, createprocessasuser

I try to create python script to start process as user (In future this code will be run from session 0 by windows service). For this i decide to use win32api.

But I have an error:

```
win32process.CreateProcessAsUser(token, None, "c:\\windows\\notepad.exe", None, None, 0, 0, None, None, startup)
pywintypes.error: (1314, 'CreateProcessAsUser', 'A required privilege is not held by the client.')
```

What privilege? I think I'm already gave all privileges, if I correctly understand [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/privilege-constants?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

My code:

```
import win32con
import win32process
import win32security
import win32api


def adjust_privilege(privilege, enable=1):
    flags = win32security.TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | win32security.TOKEN_QUERY
    htoken = win32security.OpenProcessToken(
        win32api.GetCurrentProcess(), flags)
    id = win32security.LookupPrivilegeValue(None, privilege)
    if enable:
        new_privilege = [(id, win32security.SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED)]
    else:
        new_privilege = [(id, 0)]
    win32security.AdjustTokenPrivileges(htoken, 0, new_privilege)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    adjust_privilege(win32security.SE_TCB_NAME)
    adjust_privilege(win32security.SE_ASSIGNPRIMARYTOKEN_NAME)
    adjust_privilege(win32security.SE_INCREASE_QUOTA_NAME)

    user = "username"
    password = "password"
    domain = "domain"
    logontype = win32con.LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE
    provider = win32con.LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT50
    token = win32security.LogonUser(user, domain, password, logontype, provider)
    startup = win32process.STARTUPINFO()
    startup.dwFlags = win32process.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
    startup.wShowWindow = win32con.SW_SHOW
    startup.lpDesktop = 'winsta0\default'
    win32process.CreateProcessAsUser(token, None, "c:\\windows\\notepad.exe", None, None, 0, 0, None, None, startup)
```

I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: simply read msdn at very begin - *Typically, the process that calls the `CreateProcessAsUser` function must have the `SE_INCREASE_QUOTA_NAME` privilege and may require the `SE_ASSIGNPRIMARYTOKEN_NAME` privilege* and in your case you need use `CreateProcessWithLogonW` instead `LogonUser + CreateProcessAsUser`

Comment: and you not check result of `AdjustTokenPrivileges` - if you **try** get `SE_ASSIGNPRIMARYTOKEN_NAME` - this yet not mean that you really get it (tcb here not need)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, here is an example on msdn to [Starting an Interactive Client Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aa379608(v=vs.85)).

Second, As @RbMm pointer out:

you need use [`CreateProcessWithLogonW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createprocesswithlogonw) instead `LogonUser` + `CreateProcessAsUser`

According to the document:

> If this function fails with `ERROR_PRIVILEGE_NOT_HELD` (1314), use the
>   `CreateProcessWithLogonW` function instead.

[This](https://gist.github.com/liantian-cn/27c4836a2d96c902258d) seems to be an example used in Python.

Other useful articles：

[Launching an interactive process from Windows Service in Windows Vista and later](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/winsdk/2009/07/14/launching-an-interactive-process-from-windows-service-in-windows-vista-and-later/)

Comment: Thanks for useful information. I tried 1.A example from this link [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/winsdk/2009/07/14/launching-an-interactive-process-from-windows-service-in-windows-vista-and-later/)

Launch a hidden temporary process as explained in step 1.A.

I. Get the user token by calling WTSQueryUserToken 
WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId (), &hToken) ;

II. Use this token in CreateProcessAsUser to launch the temporary process.
 
But I had the same problems with privileges.

Comment: According to the [return value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/securitybaseapi/nf-securitybaseapi-adjusttokenprivileges#return-value) in docs: **To determine whether the function adjusted all of the specified privileges, call GetLastError, which returns one of the following values when the function succeeds** if error == `ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED`, The token does not have one or more of the privileges specified in the NewState parameter. The function may succeed with this error value even if no privileges were adjusted.

Comment: It is recommended to use `CreateProcessWithLogonW` according to the document